# Как узнать количество пользователей бота

Tags: python, telebot, бот, telegram

у меня есть бот в телеге  с 3 пользователями и мне нужен вывод количества пользователей по команде. Как это реализовать??

вот бот кому интересно

```
import telebot
import config
from telebot import types
from perem import p0, aboutus, gar, mor, bu, con, insr 



bot = telebot.TeleBot(config.TOKEN)

joinedFile = open(r"joined.txt" )
joinedUsers = set()
for line in joinedFile:
    
    joinedUsers.add(line.strip())
joinedFile.close()

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'] )
def start(message):
    if not str(message.chat.id) in joinedUsers:
        
        joinedFile = open("joined.txt",'w')
        joinedFile.write(str(message.chat)  )
        joinedUsers.add("\n" + str(message.chat.id))
        
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("О НАС‍", callback_data = 'about')
    markup.add(button1)
    button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("О ПРОЕКТЕ ", callback_data = 'aboutprog')
    markup.add(button2)
    button3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("✅ГАРАНТИИ✅‍", callback_data = 'garant')
    markup.add(button3)
    button4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("ℹ️ДОП.ИНФОРМАЦИЯℹ️", callback_data = 'more')
    markup.add(button4)
    button5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("ПОКУПКА‍", callback_data = 'buy')
    markup.add(button5)
    button6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("СВЯЗЬ С НАМИ", callback_data = 'connect')
    markup.add(button6)
       
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, '⬇️ГЛАВНОЕ МЕНЮ⬇️', reply_markup=markup)


@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: True)
def callback_worker(call):
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup()
    button7 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("⏪ВЕРНУТЬСЯ⏪‍", callback_data = 'back')
    button8 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("ОБРАТНАЯ СВЯЗЬ‍", url = 'https://t.me/mnogoOTVETOV_manager' )
    button9 = types.InlineKeyboardButton( '❇️ИНСТРКУЦИЯ❇️', callback_data =  'intr')
    if call.data == "about":
        markup.add(button7)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, aboutus, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == "aboutprog":
        markup.add(button7)    
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, p0, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == "garant":
        markup.add(button7)    
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, gar, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == "more":
        bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id -1 )
        markup.add(button7)    
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, mor, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == "buy":
        bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id -1 )
        markup.add(button9) 
        markup.add(button7)    
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, bu, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == "connect":
        markup.add(button8) 
        markup.add(button7)    
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, con, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == "intr":
        markup.add(button7)    
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, insr, reply_markup=markup)
    elif call.data == 'back':
        
        button1 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("О НАС‍", callback_data = 'about')
        
        button2 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("О ПРОЕКТЕ ", callback_data = 'aboutprog')
        
        button3 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("✅ГАРАНТИИ✅‍", callback_data = 'garant')
        
        button4 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("ℹ️ДОП.ИНФОРМАЦИЯℹ️", callback_data = 'more')
        
        button5 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("ПОКУПКА‍", callback_data = 'buy')
        
        button6 = types.InlineKeyboardButton("СВЯЗЬ С НАМИ", callback_data = 'connect')
        
        markup.add(button1, button2  )
        markup.add(button3, button4)
        markup.add (button5, button6)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, "Вы вернулись в меню",reply_markup=markup)
 
        
            
    


@bot.message_handler(commands=['secret'])
def send(message):
    for user in joinedUsers:
        bot.send_message(user, message.text[message.text.find(' '):])
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["text"])
def repeat_all_messages(message):
    bot.delete_message(message.chat.id, message.message_id -1 )
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Hello World')
    
##
bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

Comment: Записывать всех в Бд, и вот оттуда вы и узнаете сколько их у вас

Comment: Если возможно, то проще всего писать в SQLite

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы выводить количество пользователей бота, вам нужно записывать каждого пользователя в базу данных, а потом выводить от туда данные.

Советую использовать Базу данных **sqlite3**

Вот примеры использования данный Базы данных

- [Пример 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AkeU_O35plA)
- [Пример 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBbVadGMBAw)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 0):

Воспользуйтесь БД sqlite3, создайте таблицу с уникальным message.from_user.id.
Из каждого комментария будет выбираться id комментатора и заноситься в таблицу.